# The last form-data submited keeps getting added to an array everytime page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, forms, post, page-refresh, express-handlebars

I am using a post request to add input data from a form. This data is pushed to an array variable `burg` and then placed into my index.handlebars view. All of this works, but on refresh(when nothing is in the form) the array adds another instance of the data that was just pushed into the array. I am trying to figure out how to cancel this refresh functionality(keep the array the same and only clear the form input and display area where `burg` is placed.

display for array list and form in index.handlebars

```
 <ul>
            {{#each burg}}
            <li>{{this}}</li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>



<form class="form-group" method="post" action="/">
        <label>Add to Eat</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add" name="add" placeholder="Unique Burger Details">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add-btn">
          <span class="fa fa-book"></span> Add Ur Burger</button>
      </form>
```

all of controller.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
 let burg=[];
router.post("/", (req, res, next) =>{
burg.push(req.body.add);
res.render("index",{burg});
res.end;
});
```

section of server.js

```
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index",{burg});
}
  app.use("/", burgerRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="add" name="add" placeholder="Unique Burger Details" `required`>

Try this maybe it will do the job add the required in the tag

Comment: Thanks, but tried with no success. I also see a warning message from Firefox when refreshing the page "To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier." Chrome does the same thing sans the message. Could it be functionality that is not prone to happen when running a local server when variables are not stored and and taken out from a database?